# Gnu radio and Yaesu CAT over serial

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to take info from my radio (ft817) over serial connection and give them to gnuradio in order to use them to make a nice GUI for a panadapter. I normally print CAT data like this, please excuse my python skills I'm still learning :
`

```
import serial
import time    
SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
SAMPLES_PER_SEC = 5
class FT817(object):
    

    SERIAL_SPEED = 9600
    SERIAL_STOPBITS = serial.STOPBITS_TWO
    SERIAL_TIMEOUT = 1.0
    # Transceiver modes and commands
    MODES = ["LSB", "USB", "CW", "CWR", "AM", None, "WFM", None, "FM", None, "DIG", None, "PKT"]
    CMD_READ_FREQ = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03]
    CMD_READ_RX_STATUS = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE7]
    
    def __init__(self, serial_port, serial_speed=SERIAL_SPEED, serial_stopbits=SERIAL_STOPBITS):
        self._serial = serial.Serial(serial_port, serial_speed, stopbits=serial_stopbits, timeout=FT817.SERIAL_TIMEOUT)
        self._frequency = ""
        self._mode = ""
        self._squelch = True
        self._s_meter = ""
        
    def read_frequency(self):
        '''Queries transceiver RX frequency and mode.
        The response is 5 bytes: first four store frequency and
        the fifth stores mode (AM, FM, SSB etc.)
        '''
        cmd = FT817.CMD_READ_FREQ
        self._serial.write(cmd)
        resp = self._serial.read(5)
        resp_bytes = ((resp[0]), (resp[1]), (resp[2]), (resp[3]))
        self._frequency = "%02x%02x%02x%02x" % resp_bytes
        self._mode = FT817.MODES[(resp[4])]
        
    def read_rx_status(self):
        '''Queries transceiver RX status.
        The response is 1 byte:
        bit 7: Squelch status: 0 - off (signal present), 1 - on (no signal)
        bit 6: CTCSS/DCS Code: 0 - code is matched, 1 - code is unmatched
        bit 5: Discriminator centering: 0 - discriminator centered, 1 - uncentered
        bit 4: Dummy data
        bit 3-0: S Meter data
        '''
        cmd = FT817.CMD_READ_RX_STATUS
        self._serial.write(cmd)
        resp = self._serial.read(1)
        resp_byte = (resp[0])
        self._squelch = True if (resp_byte & 0B10000000) else False
        
 
    def get_trx_state_string(self):
        '''Returns transceiver state data for printing.
        '''
    
        sql_str = 'SQL: ON' if self._squelch else 'SQL: OFF'
        res = "%sHz %s %s" % (self._frequency, self._mode, sql_str)
        return res
    
    def __str__(self):
        '''Overrides __str__() method for using FT817 class with print command.
        '''
        return self.get_trx_state_string()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting FT-817ND monitor...")
    
    try:
        ft817 = FT817(SERIAL_PORT)
        delay = 1.0 / SAMPLES_PER_SEC
        while True:
            ft817.read_frequency()
            ft817.read_rx_status()
            print
            print (ft817)
            time.sleep(delay)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # KeyboardInterrupt exception is thrown when CTRL-C or CTRL-Break is pressed. 
        pass
    finally:
        print ("See you later. 73!")
```

`
But i'm not sure how to implement this in GNURADIO, any help?

I've tried to use py block but without success.

Comment: "Please port this code to GNU Radio" is much too broad to be on-topic -- Stack Overflow questions are expected to be about a narrow, specific technical question.

Comment: BTW, 5 samples per second is really, _really_ low from GR's perspective; it's designed for much higher-throughput devices. Not having very much data to handle gives you extra options -- like keeping your software outside of GR and pushing content through a message bus, for example.

Comment: (...you might also try your hand at modernizing the gr-pyserial block; it'll need some work to get it going again, but if you're successful you'll have something not specific to your individual device).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't realized I was OT if needed i can remove this thread. Thanks for the amazing advice, I'll have a look on it and report back!

Comment: GRC questions definitely _can_ be on-topic, the trick is to make them narrow and specific. Showing the block you tried to write and asking about a specific problem you're stuck on (after the usual good-faith search for other answers about that specific problem), f/e, won't run into the scoping rules.